# Static class in TypeScript type

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to create a Typescript type for a series of static classes (for having a type on an array with several static classes) How do I define the static version of the classes as part of the type? The following code will require an instance of the class (with new staticClass1)

```
type myType = staticClass1 | staticClass2 | staticClass3
```

Any suggestions on how I make the type for the static version of the classes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `typeof staticClass1` to create a type that matches the static members of the class (or rather, the members defined on `staticClass1` itself, not its prototype).